# Run add .env, so we can use .env params in app.conf with brace?

Tags: go, beego

how can I run and pack with .env file, use bee-cli?, so the app.conf can read .env params with brace, like this:

```
appname = ${APP_NAME}
```

In my VSCode launch.json，I set like this:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Package",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.go",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

so, I can debug with .env file.

---------0320---------------
I found A doc below [the link](https://github.com/beego/beedoc/blob/master/en-US/module/config.md#how-to-obtain-environment-variables).
https://github.com/beego/beedoc/blob/master/en-US/module/config.md#how-to-obtain-environment-variables

but I use beego v1.12.3. How this version to obtain Environment Variables?

-------------------------update-----------------------

My project has an .env file:

```
ADMIN_PORT=17201

ADMIN_ADDR=127.0.0.1

DATABASE_URL=127.0.0.1

MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

and I want get values like this:
/conf/app.conf

```
AdminAddr = ${ADMIN_ADDR}
AdminPort = ${ADMIN_PORT}
```

when I execute the command : bee run
It throw an error, like this:

```
panic: prefix should has path
```

In my project it means, app.conf can not get .env vaules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should import

```
_ "github.com/joho/godotenv/autoload"
```

import godotenv before all packages